# How to add custom form element fckeditor in zend framework

Tags: php, zend-framework, fckeditor

I want to use fckeditor in my website using zend framework.

Can any one explain how can we add custom form elements with zend framework ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not the "good practice" here - to give a link, but I don't think this question can be answered better without copy-paste:

http://www.leftcolumn.net/2009/03/10/zend-framework-how-to-add-fckeditor-to-a-zend_form/

http://www.zfsnippets.com/snippets/view/id/55

ps: I'm curious, why did not you google for first http://www.google.ru/search?q=zend+form+fckeditor+&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:ru:official&client=firefox ?

Comment: Huh? What changes? There are no any changes - it is `extending`, and it is a **good practice**.

Comment: http://www.zfsnippets.com/snippets/view/id/55 is saying for changes in zend library folder. IS it good to make changes in core zend folder ?

Comment: @seed_of_tree: no, it is not. You can create **your own** class in any directory you want. In that sample they create it in directory `library/Zend` because they wanted it. And it is not the fact, that Zend itself is there. It is a common practice to have **empty** directory `library/Zend` and fill it with your classes.