# Zend framework fckeditor integration

Tags: php, zend-framework, url-rewriting

I have done integration of fckeditor with zend framework.

have using custom view helper.

and its calling fckeditor class now

my problem is that it's (fckeditor class)  using iframe to show fckeditor. Here Zend  frame work url not working.

Iframe link built by eckeditor class is :

```
/mysite/public/js/fckeditor/editor/fckeditor.html?InstanceName=page_text_details
```

it's giving below error due to iframe link to fckeditor.html

```
Uncaught exception 'Zend_Controller_Dispatcher_Exception' with message 'Invalid controller specified (js)' in /var/www/html/......
```

Please help me how can i remove this.

Even i have used htacces to rewrite URL

my htaccess file is :

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]

RewriteRule !\.(htm|html|txt|swf|js|ico|gif|jpg|png|css|php|xml|pdf|cab)$ index.php [NC,L]
```

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4311049/how-to-add-custom-form-element-fckeditor-in-zend-framework

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add a rewritebase rule in your htaccess :

```
RewriteBase /mysite/public
```

You may want to verify that your 'js' folder exists (and its fckeditor dependances) under the public folder